# SQL Server 2014 - remote login to AOAG named instance, listener port does not work

Tags: availability-groups, connectivity, remote

Your help is greatly appreciated.
I spent a few hours trying to troubleshoot this and before I go to the firewall/network possibilities, i would like to check if my setup has any errors

I am unable to remote connect from my desktop using the VNN and port# to the named instance on non default port in the AOAG

Local connection tests - successful
a) servername\instancename
b)servername, port#
c)server ip\instancename
d)serverip, port#
e)aoag listener\instancename
f)aoaglistener, port#
g)aoag listenerip\instancename
h)aoaglistenerip, port#

Remote connection from desktop - successful if using server and instance names.
But it fails if I try remote connection with VIP/VNN
e)aoag listener\instancename
f)aoaglistener, port#
g)aoag listenerip\instancename
h)aoaglistenerip, port#

I would like to use the separate AOAGlistener and port#s in the connection string.

I have validated -

1. firewall rules work as tested from remote desktop using server ip and instancename/port#
2. username password works
3. using static ip and port#
4. tcp is enabled and active/enabled are yes for each ip
5. remote connectio is enabled.

## Error information

## Cannot connect to aoag_lsnr, 1551.

### A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Server Name: aoag_lsnr, 1551
Error Number: 64
Severity: 20
State: 0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Examine the answers found here.  There are several answers that may lead you to your solution.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270199/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occ

Comment: This could be due to different reason. The most probable cause is UDP port is not open. Try to open UDP for the  same number (as tcp).

Comment: Do a network capture and see what is happening... Also Listeners don't use the browser service and have no idea what instance names are. Listeners, in fact, can't have instance names.